# Is it possible to use bootstrap themes on a Mezzanine/Cartridge website?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, mezzanine, cartridge

I am a newbie web developer tasked with creating a website for a client in the art industry. I've decided to roll with Mezzanine + Cartridge for the project as it seems like an accessible way to get started. I now have the server up and running with no issues, but obviously can't use the default Mezzanine theme for such a project.

I'm finding that theres a highly limited amount of themes available online for Mezzanine, and that there are a lot more Bootstrap themes available floating around. Is there a way I could use the two together? Ie the UI/front end being a Bootstrap theme while still maintaining the functionality of Mezz/Cartridge?

If so, how would I go about doing this? Not expecting a step by step guide, but any advice/guidance would be highly appreciated. Like I said, I'm incredibly new to this (first website ever!) so if I'm misunderstanding something, please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll override the base template as the starting point for customizing the look of everything. In there you'll find the stylesheets for bootstrap used, which you can modify/replace/etc.

https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/32dc38778d296f508a23b729de04a02075994df5/mezzanine/core/templates/base.html#L18-L32